# Tortoise SVN Branching Issue

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

So I checked out a branch...

1. made changes
2. did an update on the branch (there was nothing & wouldn't be anyway)
3. commited changes
4. updated my working copy of trunk
5. Reintegrated a branch to the trunk & merged
6. commited trunk

I then made further changes on my branch the...

1. commited the changes
2. updated my working copy of trunk
3. Reintegrated a branch to the trunk & merged

But my changes were not there! I could not see them on the local working copy? I chose the option to 'keep from repository' on any conflicting files, but they were not there?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reintegrating a branch should only be done when you are finished with that branch and don't plan on using it again - because it can't be used for merging in the future. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate

> Once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no longer usable for further work. It's not able to correctly absorb new trunk changes, nor can it be properly reintegrated to trunk again. For this reason, if you want to keep working on your feature branch, we recommend destroying it and then re-creating it from the trunk

There is [a way to not have to do this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice), but I think you've passed the point where it's still applicable.